# Inner Product Space - Orthonormality

Tags: inner-products, orthonormal

I'm studying a orthonormality of inner product space using Kreyszig's Functional Analysis textbook. I'm having difficulty with some parts of it. I quoted the section that I have problem with and the questions are at the bottom of this post.

If we know that a given $x$ can be represented as a linear combination of some elements of an orthonormal sequence, then the orthonormality makes the actual
determination of the coefficients very easy. In fact, if $(e_1, e_2, ... )$ is an
orthonormal sequence in an inner product space $X$ and we have $x \in span$ $\{e_1. ... , e_n\}$, where $n$ is fixed, then 
$$ x = \sum_{k=1}^n  \alpha_k e_k, \tag6$$

and if we take the inner product by a fixed $e_j$, we obtain

$$ \langle x,e_j \rangle = \langle\sum  \alpha_k e_k,e_j \rangle = \sum  \alpha_k \langle e_k,e_j \rangle = \alpha_j, $$

With these coefficients, (6) becomes

$$ x  = \sum_{k=1}^n  \langle x,e_k \rangle e_k. \tag 7$$
This shows that the determination of the unknown coefficients in (6) is
simple. Another advantage of orthonormality becomes apparent if in
(6) and (7) we want to add another term $\alpha_{n+1}e_{n+1}$ to take care of an

$$ \widetilde x = x + \alpha_{n+1}e_{n+1}\in \{e_1,\ldots,e_{n+1}\}; $$

then we need to calculate only one more coefficient since the other coefficients remain unchanged.

More generally, if we consider any $x \in X$, not necessarily in $Y_n = span \{e_1, \ldots ,e_n\}$, we can define $y \in Y_n$ by setting

$$ y  = \sum_{k=1}^n   \langle x,e_k \rangle e_k, \tag {8a}$$
where $n$ is fixed, as before, and then define $z$ by setting

$$x = y + z, \tag {8b}$$

that is, $z = x - y$. We want to show that $z \perp y$. To really understand
what is going on, note the following. Every $y \in Y_n$ is a linear combination

$$ y = \sum_{k=1}^n  \alpha_k e_k. $$

Here $ \alpha_k= \langle y,e_k \rangle $, as follows from what we discussed right before. Our claim is that for the particular choice $ \alpha_k= \langle x,e_k \rangle, k = 1, \ldots, n,$ we
shall obtain a $y$ such that $z = x - y \perp y$.

Questions:

1) What does this specifically mean: if we consider any $x \in X$, not necessarily in $Y_n = span \{e_1, \ldots ,e_n\}$, then (8a)? What is the relationship between $X$ and $Y_n$? If they are spanned by the same basis, then aren't they the same such that $X = Y$? Which is why it is confusing.

2) Doesn't (8a) actually mean that $ y = x$?

3) The last sentence: Our claim is that for the particular choice $ \alpha_k= \langle x,e_k \rangle, k = 1, \ldots, n,$ we shall obtain a $y$ such that $z = x - y \perp y$. 
How does the choice of  $ \alpha_k$ imply $z = x - y \perp y$?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

1) The set $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is a *finite subset* of the orthonormal sequence; it’s not the entire sequence. Its span $Y_n$ is thus a finite-dimensional proper subspace of the infinite-dimensional space $X$.

2) If $x$ happens to be an element of $Y_n$, then of course, $y=x$. If $x\notin Y_n$, however, there’s no linear combination of the vectors $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ that can equal $x$.

3) To see this formally, compute $$\begin{align} \langle y,z\rangle &= \langle y,x-y\rangle \\ &= \langle y,x\rangle-\langle y,y\rangle \\ &= \langle\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ie_i,x\rangle-\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i^2 \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\langle e_i,x\rangle-\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i^2 \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i^2-\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i^2 \\ &=0.\end{align}$$ For an informal explanation, see below.

You can visualize what’s going on here quite easily in $X=\mathbb R^3$. An orthonormal sequence in $\mathbb R^3$ is necessarily finite, but that doesn’t make any fundamental difference. A subset of such a sequence $\{e_1,e_2\}$ spans some plane $Y_2$ through the origin. If take $x\notin Y_2$, we can decompose it into a component $y$ that lies within the plane and a component $z$ that’s outside of it. The in-plane component $y=\langle x,e_1\rangle e_1+\langle x,e_2\rangle e_2$ is just the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $Y_2$. The other component, $z$, is what’s left over after you subtract this from $x$. This is the orthogonal *rejection* of $x$ from $Y_2$ and must be orthogonal to this plane. If it weren’t, at least one of $\langle z,e_1\rangle$ or $\langle z,e_2\rangle$ would be non-zero, but those components of $x$ have already been accounted for in $y$.